# How to write css properties for efficient rendering

Tags: css, dom, browser, rendering, interpreter

I am just a bit curious to know how do browser interpret properties of CSS, is there any order in which browser pics and apply CSS or it is first come and first serve ?
Like, if I write

```
.test-class{
  color: black;
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

and

```
.test-class{
  position: absolute;
  color: black;
  height: 20px;
  width: 10px;
}
```

Are they both interpreted in same time, or there is order(like first positioning, then coloring etc are implemented) of implementation.
If there is an order of implementation of these properties, is it a pointer to make it(page rendering) more efficient ?

Comment: http://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm

Comment: @Paulie_D can you point specifically to the explaination, I cannot grab where it answers the question ?